# How to create multiple checkbox using JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2

I need to make a group of checkbox in JSF. Can anyone guide me to create checkboxes using JSF component(s) with example?

Comment: Seems you are looking for something like [this][1]. [1]:http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-checkboxes-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in as JSF programe

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{emp.Hobby1}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Hobby - 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Hobby - 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Hobby - 3" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

At runtime it will be converted to below html code

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="j_idt6:j_idt10" id="j_idt6:j_idt10:0" value="1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="j_idt6:j_idt10:0" class=""> Hobby - 1</label></td>
  <td>
    <input name="j_idt6:j_idt10" id="j_idt6:j_idt10:1" value="2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="j_idt6:j_idt10:1" class=""> Hobby - 2</label></td>
  <td>
    <input name="j_idt6:j_idt10" id="j_idt6:j_idt10:2" value="3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="j_idt6:j_idt10:2" class=""> Hobby - 3</label></td>
  <td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help could you also guide me to write the backend bean code for the same?

Comment: just create a variable of type array in your bean public `String[] hobby1` and its etter getter. create a method which will return the values as array to string like `public String getHobby1InString() {
  return Arrays.toString(hobby1);
 }`;